# How to delete Google Drive files with GNOME online account?

Tags: 18.04, online-accounts, google-drive

I have Ubuntu 18.04. I can mount my Google Drive and copy files. But, I cannot delete files. Is it not possible to delete files?

Comment: What are you using to delete files? What happens?

Comment: What do you use to mount the drive?

Comment: Google Drive is an on-line cloud. Removing files : Right click file, and select `Remove` = the trash can symbol.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I use the file explorer included in Ubuntu: Nautilus. Nothing happens when I press the delete key.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani , I mount the drive using Nautilus.

Comment: @KnudLarsen , I know that Drive is on-line cloud. But, I can create profiles with Gnome online accounts. This way I can mount Drive, and the files appear in the file manager (Nautilus). I can copy files, but I cannot delete files

Comment: A cloud storage is considered a safe backup. If your local files are attacked, or if an error removes the local folder, the On-line 'Google Drive' is supposed to be untouched. .... I.e. "not allowed to delete files" is a security measure.

Comment: Hi @KnudLarsen
Dropbox is also a cloud storage. And I can install a package that allows to sync and delete files. Do you mean that gnome online accounts is different?

Comment: I am using 19.10 and I ***can*** delete Google Drive files from Nautilus using the `Del` key or the right click menu.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was trying to delete documents shared with me. I have discovered that shared files appear when I select to show hidden files in the file manager (Nautilus). In order to avoid confusions I think it is better no show hidden files.